# Oracle: Aging - 7 Buckets - By Account Report Definition (ARXAGS)

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oraclereports, oracleapplications

Is it possible to get the code file behind a standard Oracle report from a resource other than my IT department?

I only have minimal read-only permissions on our server, and the IT folks here are not willing to share this information with me.

I am trying to write a query similar to the standard report: Aging - 7 Buckets  - By Account Report and would like to see the tables/logic that are behind it to point me in the right direction.

Is this data available anywhere? We are on version 11.5.10.2

Comment: Here's some light Oracle reading for your version: http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B25284_01/current/html/docset.html

Comment: The problem is, that information is strictly proprietary to Oracle and it would be a breach of contract for anybody to publish the information here.  Seriously, your best bet is to resolve your differences with the IT department.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to easily extract the underlying SQL logic for this very report by simply viewing the concurrent request log file. The log file includes the executed SQL and lexical parameters. I used this approach to migrate this very seeded report to another custom Oracle BI solution.